# Composition of 2 Normal random variables

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

If $$ X\sim N(0,1)$$

and,
$$Y=
 \begin{cases}
  X, & \text{with probability 0.5 }\\
  -X, & \text{with probability 0.5}
 \end{cases}
$$

Show that $$ Y\sim N(0,1)$$
 but $(X,Y)$ is not bivariate normal. Reason: since the bivariate pdf is non-zero only on the lines $y=\pm x$.

How do we show that Y is normal and why is the reason given sufficient that $(X,Y)$ is not bivariate normal.

Comment: The exercise as stated is **wrong**. Consider $$Z=|X|$$ then you might agree that, indeed, $$Z=\begin{cases}X, & \text{with probability 0.5 }\\-X, & \text{with probability 0.5}\end{cases}$$ but $Z$ is obviously not normally distributed, right?

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

1. If $(X,Y)$ was bivariate normal, then what would the pdf be? Where would it be zero?
2. Try to compute $P(Y \leq s)$. Analyze the cases when $X = Y$ and $-X = Y$ separately.(Presumably the 1/2 coinflip in the definition is happening independently of $X$, otherwise you could cook up a situation when $Y = |X|$, which I think is not the intention.) How do the distributions for $X$ and $-X$ compare?

Comment: For 1. It would be zero nowhere right?

Comment: @matt Yes. Also, the distribution which your assignment describes as "non-zero only on $y = \pm x$"... I think its probably more clear to say that it doesn't have a probability mass function, but if it did then the pmf would be on $y = \pm x$ (more advanced aside: you can make sense of the support of a distribution in $\mathbb{R}^2$, because it is strongly Lindelof : every open covering of an open set has a countable subcover, so you can define a largest measure-0 open). (Note that any function that is nonzero only on $y = \pm x$ will have zero integral, hence not be a pmf.)